# How to create a new Solana SPL Token and account using solana-py

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I am running into some issues when trying to create tokens using [solana-py](https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/index.html), I have seen the [python functions for the SPL client](https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/spl.html) but I don't really know how to use it. For instance, how could I replicate the following Solana CLI actions using solana-py:

```
spl-token create-token
spl-token create-account <TOKEN>
spl-token mint <TOKEN> 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to read through the tests to see how it's used.

- The official solana-py test to create an SPL token account: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/eb03b092a9a013578caab2e7a07ebcb5e44d84d1/tests/integration/test_token_client.py#L66

If you find these too complicated, since they're using a helper class, the stake pool program has some wrappers which may make this clearer.

- Token helpers: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/stake-pool/py/spl_token/actions.py
- Tests using them: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/stake-pool/py/tests/test_token.py

From there, you should be able to piece together all three actions that you're trying to perform.

Answer (score 0):

AUG-2022

How to create a new token account to send token to with solana-py

What you will need: 1. Token Address. It is the unique identifier of your token that is provided to you when you first make it.

```
from spl.token.instructions import create_associated_token_account
from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.transaction import Transaction

mint_public_id = PublicKey("")
new_wallet = Keypair.generate()
transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(
    create_associated_token_account(
        new_wallet.public_key, #who is paying for the creation of this token account?
        new_wallet.public_key, #who is the owner of this new token account?
        mint_public_id #what tokens should this token account be able to receive?

    )
)

client_devnet = Client(endpoint="https://api.devnet.solana.com", commitment=Confirmed)
client_devnet.request_airdrop(new_wallet.public_key,1000000000)
client_devnet.get_balance(new_wallet.public_key)
client_devnet.send_transaction(
    transaction, new_wallet, opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, preflight_commitment=Confirmed))
```

KEYWORDS: solana-py token account token python create token account with python

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you still struggle to create a token on Solana Blockchain, some website UI allows you to create your without any coding knowledge like :

- https://www.skunka-tools.xyz
- https://www.spl-token-ui.com